# fcm registration token stored automatically into firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, mobile, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new in push notification using FCM. I am afraid when I used FCM, it will give me some pricing when the device register the FCM device token. Is that token will stored into firebase database automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, the token is not stored in the Realtime Database, and there is no charge for using FCM.